# Golang: get the type of slice

Tags: arrays, go, reflection, slice, go-reflect

I am using reflect package to get the type of arbitrary array, but getting

```
   prog.go:17: cannot use sample_array1 (type []int) as type []interface {} in function argument [process exited with non-zero status]
```

How do I get the type from array?  I know how to get it from value.

```
  func GetTypeArray(arr []interface{}) reflect.Type {
      return reflect.TypeOf(arr[0])
  }
```

http://play.golang.org/p/sNw8aL0a5f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
GetTypeArray(arr []interface{})
```

to:

```
GetTypeArray(arr interface{})
```

By the way, `[]int` is not an array but a *slice* of integers.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of the potential index-out-of-bounds panic. See my answer.

Comment: @Mike Even though you are correct, that is not the question (which includes a very specific error to solve) and hence it's out of scope here.

Comment: The title of the question is "Golang , Go : get the type of array", and that's what I was looking for when I found it. I'm not suggesting that it's your bug or that you missed it. However, it's important that it be addressed because I almost used this code without noticing the bug or the fact that the solution was suboptimal. I'm not trying to challenge you, I just think it's important.

Answer (score 39):

The fact that you're indexing the slice is unsafe - if it's empty, you'll get an index-out-of-range runtime panic. Regardless, it's unnecessary because of the [reflect package's `Elem()` method](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type):

```
type Type interface {

    ...

    // Elem returns a type's element type.
    // It panics if the type's Kind is not Array, Chan, Map, Ptr, or Slice.
    Elem() Type

    ...
}
```

So, here's what you want to use:

```
func GetTypeArray(arr interface{}) reflect.Type {
      return reflect.TypeOf(arr).Elem()
}
```

Note that, as per @tomwilde's change, the argument `arr` can be of absolutely any type, so there's nothing stopping you from passing `GetTypeArray()` a non-slice value at runtime and getting a panic.

Comment: Please also note @thwd's semantics note: `[]int` is a _slice_ of integers, not an array. Don't get confused by the use of "Array" and "arr" here. `GetTypeArray` will work for either - array or slice - and therefore a name like `GetElemType` would be better.