# How are interfaces represented in Go?

Tags: memory, types, interface, go

I'm reading through two articles right now and am a little confused.

This article - http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection says

```
> var r io.Reader
tty, err := os.OpenFile("/dev/tty", os.O_RDWR, 0)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
r = tty
```

> r contains, schematically, the (value, type) pair, (tty, *os.File).
>   Notice that the type *os.File implements methods other than Read; even
>   though the interface value provides access only to the Read method,
>   the value inside carries all the type information about that value.

This other article, says

> In terms of our example, the itable for Stringer holding type Binary
>   lists the methods used to satisfy Stringer, which is just String:
>   Binary's other methods (Get) make no appearance in the itable.

[image]

It feels like these two are in opposition. According to the second article, the variable r in the first extract should be (tty, io.Reader), as that is the static type of r. Instead, the article says that *os.File is the type of tty. If the second example were right, then the diagram in the first example should have all of the methods implemented by the Binary type.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two articles are explaining a similar concept at two very different levels of granularity. As Volker said, "Laws of Reflection" is a basic overview of what is actually happening when you examine objects *via reflection*. Your second article is examining the dynamic dispatch properties of an interface (which, can be resolved via reflection as well) and how the runtime resolves them *at runtime*.

> According to the second article, the variable r in the first extract should be (tty, io.Reader)

Given that understanding, think of an interface at runtime as a "wrapper object". It exists to provide information about another object (the `itable` from your second article) to know where to jump to in the wrapped objects layout (implementation may differ between versions .. but the principle is basically the same for most languages).

This is why calling `Read` on `r` works .. first it will check the `itable` and jump to the function that is laid out for the `os.File` type. If that was an interface .. you would be looking at another dereference and dispatch (which IIRC isn't applicable at all in Go).

RE: Reflection - you're getting an easily digestible representation of this, in the form of a `(value, type)` pair (via the `reflect.ValueOf` and `reflect.TypeOf` methods).

Comment: Wait...so I didn't totally get that, but are you saying that they're referring to different things? When the first article says r holds (tty, * os.File), that isn't the same as the interface type being referred to in the second article? What happens in casting? Is there a reference to a new itable created (and this must be easy right because an interface is a lightweight wrapper)

Comment: I have updated my answer. To answer your question about new itables: This is all happening at compile time. So yes, you will have a reference to a new itable when you cast.. but it won't happen entirely at runtime. They will be set up during program bootstrap (as dispatch tables are in other environments).

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, r "holds" (tty, *os.File) and that is what the second article says. Note that Laws of Reflection is a bit more high-level and does not mention implementation details (which might change in each release) like discussed in the second article. The diagram of the second article read as follows: "s contains schematically (b, *Binary). s is of type Stringer, its data is a Binary with value 200 and s's itable contains one method String and the other methods of Binary (or *Binary) are not represented in the itable and thus not accessible for s.

Note that I think the actual implementation of interfaces in Go 1.4 is different from what the second article (Russ's?) states. "

Comment: Oh! How are they implemented currently??

Comment: No idea. Just take a look at the source. It is pure Go now.