# Go Pointers: Slice of interfaces changing pointer address

Tags: pointers, go, interface, slice, memory-address

Whenever I retrieve the address of an appended struct into an slice of structs that implements an interface, its pointer address seems to change.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/MmAS6S5IqH

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Apple struct {
    Rotter
    Color string
}

func (a *Apple) GetColor() string {
    return a.Color
}

type Shop struct {
    Rotters []Rotter
}

type Rotter interface {
    GetColor() string
}

func main() {
    red_apple := &Apple{Color: "Red"}

    fmt.Println(red_apple.GetColor())
    fmt.Println(&red_apple)

    grocer := &Shop{}
    grocer.Rotters = append(grocer.Rotters, red_apple)

    for _, fruit := range grocer.Rotters {
        fmt.Println(fruit.GetColor())
        fmt.Println(&fruit)

    }
}
```

As seen when printed out in the results, the addresses of the structs does change however the values stay the same.

From what I've understand online is that when a struct implements a interface, there is some additional memory data stored with the struct. (I'm assuming this is whats changing my address)

To get to my question, can I somehow change my slice or struct in order to get around this issue and hopefully not go down the reflection route. By "get around" I mean get the original address via the slice.

Comment: Kinda gotta ask why you care at all about the addresses of things. What is your actual concern?

Comment: I'm running into a few other bugs and while testing the pointer addresses i noticed this.

Comment: Line 8 is unnecessary, does nothing useful i.e. can be deleted, and its presence may confuse the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question prints the addresses of local variables `red_apple` and `fruit`. They are different variables and therefore have different addresses.

The pointer value added to the slice is the same as the value in the interface retrieved from the slice. Try this:

```
red_apple := &Apple{Color: "Red"}

fmt.Println(red_apple.GetColor())
fmt.Printf("%p\n", red_apple) // print the value in red_apple as a pointer

grocer := &Shop{}
grocer.Rotters = append(grocer.Rotters, red_apple)

for _, fruit := range grocer.Rotters {
    fmt.Println(fruit.GetColor())
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", fruit)  // print the value in fruit as a pointer
    fmt.Println(fruit == red_apple) 
}
```

[Run it on the playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/w1XNTHoNZv)

Note that this is not a printing issue. I use the `%p` format here because the output for `fmt.Println(red_apple)` and `fmt.Println(fruit)` print `&{<nil> Red}` instead of the pointer value.

The key point is that you should print the value added to and retrieved from the slice, not the address of the local variables.

Comment: Interesting. What does the `%p` do?

Comment: %p formats a pointer value in base 16 notation, with leading 0x.  I used %p because the default format for the value does not show the address.

Comment: Ah. The key is in the fmt docs: `Regardless of the verb, if an operand is an interface value, the internal concrete value is used, not the interface itself.`

Comment: So they are still not the same thing, but you print them in a way such that you get into the inner thing that is the same. Not sure why it matters, but there is a distinction.

Comment: No, to the language they are to things with two different addresses. The fmt package recognizes that the interface value holds a pointer to a concrete value, and shows you that instead.

Comment: Didnt think it was just a printing issue. Thanks.

Comment: @OliviaRuth Operands are always passed to `fmt` functions as an `interface{}`.  The `fmt` package prints the concrete values of the operands because the package wouldn't be very useful if it did otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, `red_apple` and `grocer.Rotters[0]` are not the same thing. One is a direct pointer to an Apple, and the other is a `Rotter` interface value.

A variable of an interface type is itself a pointer to a structure that is a combination of type information, and the underlying value (the real pointer in this case).

So your second printing is giving the address to the interface value, not the underlying implementation's value.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29087450/121660) has some better details on how interface values are stored.