# Conversion of a slice of string into a slice of custom type

Tags: go, type-conversion, slice

I'm quite new to Go, so this might be obvious. The compiler does not allow the following code:
(http://play.golang.org/p/3sTLguUG3l)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Card string
type Hand []Card

func NewHand(cards []Card) Hand {
    hand := Hand(cards)
    return hand
}

func main() {
    value := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    firstHand := NewHand(value)
    fmt.Println(firstHand)
}
```

The error is:
`/tmp/sandbox089372356/main.go:15: cannot use value (type []string) as type []Card in argument to NewHand`

From the specs, it looks like []string is not the same underlying type as []Card, so the type conversion cannot occur.

Is it, indeed, the case, or did I miss something?

If it is the case, why is it so? Assuming, in a non-pet-example program, I have as input a slice of string, is there any way to "cast" it into a slice of Card, or do I have to create a new structure and copy the data into it? (Which I'd like to avoid since the functions I'll need to call will modify the slice content).

Comment: By `type Card string` you are introducing an actual new type, not a type alias. `Card` is a new type which can have it's set of methods and behavior.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The underlying type of `Card` might be the same as the underlying type of `string` (which is itself: `string`), but the underlying type of `[]Card` is not the same as the underlying type of `[]string` (and therefore the same applies to `Hand`).

You cannot convert a slice of `T1` to a slice of `T2`, it's not a matter of what underlying types they have, if `T1` is not identical to `T2`, you just can't. Why? Because slices of different element types may have different memory layout (different size in memory). For example the elements of type `[]byte` occupy 1 byte each. The elements of `[]int32` occupy 4 bytes each. Obviously you can't just convert one to the other even if all values are in the range `0..255`.

But back to the roots: if you need a slice of `Card`s, why do you create a slice of `string`s in the first place? You created the *type* `Card` because it is *not* a `string` (or at least not just a `string`). If so and you require `[]Card`, then create `[]Card` in the first place and all your problems go away:

```
value := []Card{"a", "b", "c"}
firstHand := NewHand(value)
fmt.Println(firstHand)
```

Note that you are still able to initialize the slice of `Card` with *untyped* constant `string` *literals* because it can be used to initialize any type whose underlying type is `string`. If you want to involve typed `string` constants or non-constant expressions of type `string`, you need explicit conversion, like in the example below:

```
s := "ddd"
value := []Card{"a", "b", "c", Card(s)}
```

If you have a `[]string`, you need to manually build a `[]Card` from it. There is no "easier" way. You can create a helper `toCards()` function so you can use it everywhere you need it.

```
func toCards(s []string) []Card {
    c := make([]Card, len(s))
    for i, v := range s {
        c[i] = Card(v)
    }
    return c
}
```

Some links for background and reasoning:

[Go Language Specification: Conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

[why []string can not be converted to []interface{} in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325155/why-string-can-not-be-converted-to-interface-in-golang)

[Cannot convert []string to []interface {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990338/cannot-convert-string-to-interface)

[What about memory layout means that []T cannot be converted to []interface in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026241/what-about-memory-layout-means-that-t-cannot-be-converted-to-interface-in-go)

Comment: as I mentioned, this is a pet example, in my real setup, the `[]string` comes from an external source on which I have no control.

Comment: @FDO Yes, I know, but if this is a pet example, in more complex examples there is even more reason to create proper types in the first place. Look at it as in this example you don't have the required input slice, just some data from which you can produce  the required input slice.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. The output of `strings.Split`, for instance, is a `[]string`. I created the type `Card` and `Hand` because I want 'methods' for those types, and the output of `strings.Split` is used as input for those types and it seems a waste of time/cpu/code to just copy input in a new data structure.

Why would `[]string` and `[]Card` have a different memory layout ? (the `[]int32` and `[]byte` example is obvious, but in my case, it's not so obvious to me)

Comment: @FDO If you have a `[]string`, you need to manually build a `[]Card` from it. There is no "easier" way. You can create a helper `toCards()` function so you can use it everywhere you need it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'm still trying to figure out the rationale behind this design choice, so if you have any article I could read, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @FDO Added some links. Some are more general and targets `[]interface{}` but some reasoning mentioned there applies here too.

Comment: Since Golang 1.18 this can be done

    `func StringSliceToCustomStringSlice[T ~string](s []string) []T`

Answer (score 27):

There is no technical reason why conversion between slices whose elements have identical underlying types (such as `[]string` and `[]Card`) is forbidden. It was a specification decision to help avoid accidental conversions between unrelated types that by chance have the same structure.

The safe solution is to copy the slice. However, it is possible to convert directly (without copying) using the [unsafe](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe) package:

```
value := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
// convert &value (type *[]string) to *[]Card via unsafe.Pointer, then deref
cards := *(*[]Card)(unsafe.Pointer(&value))
firstHand := NewHand(cards)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/tto57DERjYa

Obligatory warning from the package documentation:

> `unsafe.Pointer` allows a program to defeat the type system and read and write arbitrary memory. It should be used with extreme care.

There was a [discussion on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/YA-X2z05VMM) about conversions and underlying types in 2011, and a [proposal to allow conversion between recursively equivalent types](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18030) in 2016 which was declined "until there is a more compelling reason".

Comment: That is an extremely interesting complimentary comment, I wish I could +1 more than once to increase its visibility.

Answer (score 1):

> From the specs, it looks like []string is not the same underlying type as []Card, so the type conversion cannot occur.

Exactly right. You have to convert it by looping and copying over each element, converting the type from `string` to `Card` on the way.

> If it is the case, why is it so? Assuming, in a non-pet-example program, I have as input a slice of string, is there any way to "cast" it into a slice of Card, or do I have to create a new structure and copy the data into it? (Which I'd like to avoid since the functions I'll need to call will modify the slice content).

Because conversions are always explicit and the designers felt that when a conversion implicitly involves a copy it should be made explicit as well.

Comment: Still, I don't understand why a copy is needed (isn't there any way to avoid it?). There's still a missing connection in my understanding.

Comment: @FDO, it's a copy because everything is go is a value. There's no way to make a variable, and assign a value without copying something, even if it's just a pointer.